# Panel not found [installed netbook edition by mistake]

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook

I installed the Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop. 1st time Ubuntu user ever. After successful  installation only panel on top with small ubuntu logo on left and system/connections, time, keyboard, volume icons/ on right. No menu and not able to create menu.

Right click on the panel - no options. I tried everything, but it could be the most basic think as i have no experience with ubuntu.

Comment: It sounds like you might have installed the Netbook edition. Can you let us know if [the screenshots on this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/features), in particular the top image is what you are seeing?

Comment: jep that exactly what i can see..

Comment: what version should i install then.. the one for desktop?

Comment: To install desktop edition download the iso from this [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop).

Comment: Did you see all the options greyed out when you right click on your panel? Or you dont see any options?

Answer (score 4):

You have installed the Netbook edition by mistake. You can install the Desktop edition on top of this (there's no need to redownload and completely reinstall Ubuntu).

Open a terminal (by typing terminal in the text box at the top of the screenshot I gave you) and in the Terminal enter `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. (This will be a reasonably large download.)

Once this is finished, click on the Power icon in the top left and click on Log Out. Now click on your user name, then at the bottom of the screen select "Desktop" as opposed to "Netbook". Finally enter your password and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button.

You should now have a standard Ubuntu Desktop install.

If you want to remove the Netbook edition: again launch the terminal (from the standard Ubuntu interface you want Applications->Accessories->Terminal) and then enter `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-netbook`.

Comment: can i also delete or "uninstall" the netbook version somehow?

Comment: @emilbochnik Yes I've updated my answer to tell you how